# Add new columns with values paired to another column

Tags: excel, merge

I have a sheet with two columns and another sheet with a *big* table.

```
A B   A B C ...
3 f   x 1 2 ...
7 x   y 2 3 ...
5 y   f 8 1 ...
. .   . . . ...
```

Is there any simple wizard or function that would merge them into a single table where the two-column table would be sorted by the values in the big table, so that it'd be paired with values in the other table? I would like to ***avoid vba*** and unnecessary sorting. The result should have one of these outputs:

```
A B C D ...       or       A B C ... X
7 x 1 2 ...                x 1 2 ... 7
5 y 2 3 ...                y 2 3 ... 5
3 f 8 1 ...                f 8 1 ... 3
. . . . ...                . . . ... .
```

Comment: It is not clear what the "merge" process will entail. You seem to have two blocks of data that need to be "merged" to produce output in one of two formats (I'm interpreting that "or" that way) but the limited data and limited description provided are not adequate to guess at what you want. Besides, it is customary to also include information about what you've tried so far and what results you're getting.

Comment: What merge process contain is in final result - a new table containing values of both, where the first column I want to merge with bigger data would be sorted by the values in one of the big table's column. Limited data? I don't think pasting 1000x1000 table would be recieved well. Limited description however, was right - I edited it, though I got the answer. What I tried was `Index` only and not really in a good way, therefore it unnecessary to post here a function that basically does nothing desired. PS: I didn't even ask for a complete solution, but if there is a way without programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, from what I understand of your question (not 100% clear as mentionned in comments), you're looking for index(match()):

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$4,MATCH(D$2:D$4,B$2:B$4,0))
```

[image]

Or, in other words:

```
=INDEX(column_that_contains_answers, MATCH(column_that_has_value_to_match,
column_that_corresponding_key_in_foreign_table,match_type))
```